# How to configure serverless.yml to read Python boolean values correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, serverless-framework

My serverless.yml file looks like this:

```
environment:
IS_OFFLINE: False
DYNAMODB_TABLE: ${self:service}-${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
iamRoleStatements: ${file(config/iam.yml)}
```

However, when I try to evaluate the `IS_OFFLINE` variable, it parses it into a string thus, making the value truthy although it's set with `False`

```
>>>> print(os.environ.get('IS_OFFLINE'))
'IS_OFFLINE': 'false'
```

If possible I would rather avoid this type of condition (in Python of all languages), if there is an alternative way of configuring the .yml file.

`if os.environ.get('IS_OFFLINE') == "true":`

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Peterhack No, just did a string check instead. Python literals are not yet translated well in serverless.

Answer (score 0):

In 2021, `true`/`false` variables in `serverless.yml` are still translated to `'true'`/`'false'` strings in Python.
You can use `strtobool` from `distutils.util` to parse them safely:

```py
from distutils.util import strtobool

if strtobool(environ.get("MY_VAR")):
```

This is a bit cleaner than string comparison and will work for many true/false synonyms like yes/no, 1/0, on/off. See https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.util.strtobool

An undefined variable will evaluate to `False`:

```py
from distutils.util import strtobool

if strtobool(environ.get("MY_UNDEFINED_VAR")):
    # this will NOT be executed
    print('var is undefined')
```